# Call Hooks on component change in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm working on an react native app.
This app use a database, the main component use 2 differents hook.

The first hook retrieves the results of a SQL query and store them in a variable.

The second hook creates a list from the first variable

Like this:

```
const [people, setPeople ] = useState([]);
useEffect (() => { 
    db.getAllPeople().then(row => setPeople(row))  
},[])

const [listData, setListData] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=> {
    setListData(
        
        Array(people.length)
            .fill('')
            .map((_, i) => ({ key: `${i}`, name: `${people[i].name}`}))
    )
}, [people]);
```

After that, my main component displays a SwipeList from the results.

Here is the problem. I am using another component to add an element to my database. When I return to my main component I would like this new element to be displayed. But the problem is that the 2 hooks are not called on the component change and the list therefore remains unchanged.

I've tried to use the useFocusEffect but it doesn't work in my case.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: use Redux or React Context API, When Store changes then affect on Provider's children Components

Comment: try ```useEffect (() => { 
if(props.navigation.isFocused){
    db.getAllPeople().then(row => setPeople(row))  
}
},[props.navigation.isFocused])```

Comment: Hello, props is for class only I think. I'm using a function for my component

Answer (score 0):

I think the useState hook manages the state of the component itself, unless you are passing this state among your parent and child or using callbacks to set the state on the component that you want to render, you could use a single source of truth to handle the changes in data, react itself will notice this changes and therefore, render the changed screens, considering that you have asynchronous operations when querying the database, a combination of redux and redux saga may help you.

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Answer (score 0):

There're one issues with your current code, or potential issues

Your second `useEffect` might get called when `people` becomes an empty list, this will reset your list data. The cure is to put a if statement inside, ex.

```
useEffect(()=> {
    if (!people) return;
    setListData(...)
}, [people]);
```

To be honest, if these two lists are connected, you shouldn't use two `hook`. The best way is to define `listData`

```
  const listData = (a function that takes people as input), ex. 
  const listData = people.map(v => v)
```

Of course, there might be a reason why you'd like to introduce more hook in complex situation, ex. `useRef`, `useMemo`.